# How can I get a crontab job to append values onto a new line instead of carrying on from the previous line?

Tags: cron

I am learning about crontabs and a tutorial that I am currently looking at gives the following example to generate a random 14-length character password:

```
cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 | head -c 14
```

An example output is this:

```
T1sBY1lX9RIAl8
```

I added this to a crontab to be run every minute and for the output to be saved / appended to an output file like so:

```
* * * * * cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 | head -c 14 >> ./passwords.log
```

The problem I am having is that I want each new entry to be added onto a new line but can't seem to figure out how.  I can only assume that `\n` is involved somewhere, but I don't know where.

So this is what I want:

```
Xf9StaSFajIfqD
UVMyQNvbWQSH7X
mM4x6ei9kDquyG
UJQXO4fYT4hqly
```

I currently get:

```
Xf9StaSFajIfqDUVMyQNvbWQSH7XmM4x6ei9kDquyGUJQXO4fYT4hqly
```

How can I achieve the former result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with something like:

```
* * * * * cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 | head -c 14 >> ./passwords.log; echo >>./passwords.log
```

The idea is to execute `echo` command which in this case print newline and add it to the file. Seems like you filter with `tr` all but letters and numbers, then get 14 of them. And no newline in this sequence

And its wise to work with absolute paths, not relative, especially with cron

Comment: I'll try that now and see what happens. Also, thanks for the tip on the paths, but I'm already fully aware of absolute vs. relative paths; remember that this is just for me to test and understand crontab better, so the paths in this context are irrelevant.

Comment: That's working nicely.  Would you explain what you did and why it works?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy, will add it in to the answer :)